# Conversion operator in Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I am trying to write a custom conversion operator to an `Eigen::Matrix2d` object, and I fail miserably. Below is the stripped-to-the-bone code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

struct MatrixView
{
    operator Eigen::Matrix2d() const // conversion operator
    {
        Eigen::Matrix2d tmp;
        std::cout << "CONVERSION TRIGERRED\n";
        return tmp; 
    }
};

int main()
{
    MatrixView m;
    static_cast<Eigen::Matrix2d>(m);
}
```

I am getting a nasty compile-time error, way too long to list here, starting with:

> error: no matching function for call to 'Eigen::Matrix::_init1(const MatrixView&)'
>
> note:   cannot convert 'x' (type 'const MatrixView') to type 'Eigen::Index {aka long int}'
>          Base::template _init1(x);
>          Base::template _init1(x);

You can find the full error message [here](http://pastebin.com/gvx9X6S5).

I have no idea what's going on, the conversion operator is trivial, it's just returning a default-initialized `Eigen::Matrix2d`. Any ideas what's wrong with it?

**EDIT**

If I remove "explicit" then the conversion is triggered by copy-initialization, like

```
Eigen::Matrix2d tmp = m; // OK without "explicit"
```

however `static_cast` still fails.

**Platform details:**

OS X 10.10 Yosemite, Eigen 3.2.6, g++ (MacPorts gcc5 5.2.0_0) 5.2.0, Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72) Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0, both fail to compile the code.

**EDIT 2**

The whole issue happened actually because my link was pointing to a developer version of Eigen_3.3_alpha1. In Eigen 3.2.x it works. Thanks @Matt for the hint! I'll close the question.

Comment: That note hints at making your operator `const`. worth a try.

Comment: @RollenD'Souza Still no difference... I actually edited the code and added the `const`, so it's now clear I'm not violating `const`-ness.

Comment: Isn't `Matrix2d` just a template for `Matrix<double, 2, 2>`.  Have you tried working with the underlying `Matrix` itself?

Comment: Not getting any compile errors myself . `g++ 4.8.3` and `eigen 3.2.5`. compiled with `-std=c++11`

Comment: @Matt It's indeed a typedef for `Matrix<double, 2, 2>`, so it should work.

Comment: @ManosNikolaidis Are you compiling the exact code I posted? I'm getting errors with both gcc (5.2) and clang, and Eigen 3.2.6.

Comment: @vsoftco There is no any `x` in code, but it appears in error message.

Comment: @vsoftco Yes the exact code you posted. Even with -Werror

Comment: @Drop It appears deep in some template instantiations that are being performed. Full error message [here](http://pastebin.com/gvx9X6S5)

Comment: @vsoftco You really want to post complete MCVE and exact errors and line numbers. My guess is that problem with `return {};` it could generate construction from initializer list.

Comment: I am able to compile the code as-is on my machine as well with libeigen3 + GCC 4.9.2 (and the conversion triggers...)

Comment: @Drop I posted a link to the full error message. There's no issue with the init_list construction, just to be safe I changed it to a typical return of a local var.

Comment: I use gcc5.2 and clang-700.0.72, both fail.

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 + Eigen 3.2.6 compiles fine. MinGW w64 GCC 5.2.0 compiles fine (with a warning)

Comment: @Drop Thanks, that's odd, there is probably something that breaks it in the new compilers, although have no idea what. I don't have right now access to a gcc < 5, will try though.

Comment: Cygwin x64 GCC 4.9.3 compiles fine

Comment: tried removing const from the operator ?

Comment: @g24l Yes, tried that, same. Although the other way around is usually problematic. A `const` member function can be invoked by non-const instances without any problem.

Comment: What is your platform, standard library and exact compiler version string? What about exact Eigen version?

Comment: Maybe there is Homebrew or some other version of eigen interferes. Try to output version: `#include <Eigen\src\Core\util\Macros.h>
std::cout << EIGEN_WORLD_VERSION << "." << EIGEN_MAJOR_VERSION << "." << EIGEN_MINOR_VERSION << "\n";`

Comment: @Drop I use eigen 3.2.6, your macro spits out 3.2.91

Comment: I just ran Drop's suggestion and got `3.2.6` using gcc 4.3.4 on SUSE Linux.  Your code also compiles fine.  Where did you get Eigen from?  The tag on the one I have is `c58038c56923`.

Comment: I use freshly downloaded [`eigen-eigen-c58038c56923.tar.bz2`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) and got `3.2.6`

Comment: Quick glance over error message revealed: `'const MatrixView' is not derived from 'const Eigen::ReturnByValue<OtherDerived>'`. This could be related to the fact that Eigen types' underlying implementations are hard to copy (things are stored in vector registers). Return could lead to copying when RVO does not happen and Eigen have some protection against it. But it is just a guess and requires more investigation.

Comment: @Matt I got the Eigen distro from the official website, http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page I used Eigen extensively, never had an issue with it, until now.

Comment: @vsoftco When I used the developmental version I got `3.2.91`.  Make sure you are including Eigen 3.2.6 and not some intermediate version.

Comment: @Matt Oh man... I had the eigen link pointing to Eigen_3.3_alpha1, stupid stupid stupid, completely forgot about the hyperlink. Eigen 3.2.6 compiles. Sorry for the mess I created, thanks much for the hint! If you write an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: @vsoftco make sure to report this as a compile error so it can be fixed before release :D

Comment: @Matt After I spend 3 hours today figuring out template error messages, be sure I will ;)

Comment: Sorry for digging this out, but did you actually file a bugreport and if so, what's the status? I couldn't find anything related.
Still having pretty much the same issue with 3.3.x. See: https://godbolt.org/z/pm6H1t

Comment: @fodinabor It worked in my case for the stable version (was failing on a devel branch). I didn't follow up after...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eigen has development packages that are produced periodically.  Following the suggestion from Drop in the comments shows how to check which version is being included.  There is one in alpha released on September 4th which returns version `3.2.91`.  Using version `3.2.6` released on October 1st does compile correctly.  The code display is the version is:

```
#include <Eigen\src\Core\util\Macros.h> 
#include <iostream>
...
std::cout << EIGEN_WORLD_VERSION << "." << EIGEN_MAJOR_VERSION << "." << 
    EIGEN_MINOR_VERSION << "\n";
```